# SpringMVC : Form processing for a survey application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring 3 MVC webapp, I need to be able to access all the submitted form fields.
Normally, I know what forms fields exist in the form and process the submitted entry using `@RequestParam`

But this form I am processing will not know what is coming in. So the only way, I know of, seems to be to do a `@RequestBody` and process the incoming POST data. My form could possibly contain arrays in it. For example. my @RequestBody could look like

```
id=1&q1_selectMultiple[]=1&q1_selectMultiple[]=2&q_2=&q_3=&Submit=Submit
```

So, to process this above string, I would need to first split the whole string at '&' and then look again for another array like q1_selectMultiple[ ] inside it and parse that as well.

This seems to be a lot of work when using a framework like Spring.

Is there a better way to do this?

PS: I looked at `@ModelAttribute`. I don't think I can use it in my case since the form is being created by one controller and the responses are being handled by a completely different controller of a different class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand your problem, but I think it would be simpler to use any of those standard ServletResponse methods such as getParameterMap(). This one returns a Map containing pairs of parameter name/values for everything submitted.

Comment: yep, you should be able to just add an HttpServletRequest parameter to your controller method and Spring will throw it in there for you, then you can get the parameter map from that.